# How to navigate through subviews in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

I think I remember reading once there is a way to navigate through the different views in Interface Builder using a keyboard shortcut (in other words select a subview that is underneath another subview by clicking on the view) but I can't seem to find what it is. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are commands for jumping between clipped (obscured) objects, but they don't have keyboard shortcuts assigned when Xcode is installed. You can set your own shortcuts in Xcode's Key Bindings preference panel, though:

[image]

Since you'll never be editing MacOS X and iOS views in the same file, you can go ahead and assign the same shortcut for corresponding commands in each editor, i.e. use one shortcut for both Jump to Next Object with Clipped Content commands.